# Get previous value of a parameter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Let us assume that we have defined the following parameter
[image]

Now, user can select a value for Data_Selekcja parameter, for example '2018-01-01'. Is there a way of getting the previous value from the list? Previous value would be '2017-07-01' in this case. I need the previous value of this parameter in a calculated field. The current value in a calculated field is given by [Parameters].[Data_Selekcja], but what about the previous value from the list.

Comment: it's quite unlikley because parameters are not treated as a proper table and so all the previous/next concepts are not available... that being said, is that parameter created from a table (having just 15 rows) or is it made from all the different date values (in your case string) from another datasource such as a fact table where those values could be repeated in date column?

Comment: There is a table from which I obtain the available dates and put them into the list of possible values for the parameter. A user selects a single date from the list. Then, I plot something based on data for the selected date (the data is in a different table). However, I would like to plot also the data for the previous date, in order to make a comparison. So I need a filter based on a calculated field. In the calculated field it's easy to refer to the current selected value, but what about the previous value from the list? Maybe I could achieve this in a different way? I'm new to Tableau.